# MySQL group by twice and COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql

Some sql query gives me the following result:

[image]

As you can see, it already has GROUP BY.

So what I need? I need to group it again (by treatment_name) and count rows for each group. See more details on screenshot.

Here is full query:

```
SELECT 
treatment_summaries.* 
FROM `treatment_summaries` 
INNER JOIN 
`treatments` 
ON 
  `treatments`.`treatment_summary_id` = `treatment_summaries`.`id` 
   AND 
  (treatment <> '' and treatment is not null) 
INNER JOIN 
`treatment_reviews` 
 ON 
    `treatment_reviews`.`treatment_id` = `treatments`.`id` 
INNER JOIN 
  `conditions_treatment_reviews` 
ON 
  `conditions_treatment_reviews`.`treatment_review_id` = `treatment_reviews`.`id` 
INNER JOIN 
  `conditions` ON `conditions`.`id` = `conditions_treatment_reviews`.`condition_id` 
INNER JOIN `conditions_treatment_summaries` `conditions_treatment_summaries_join` 
ON 
  `conditions_treatment_summaries_join`.`treatment_summary_id` = `treatment_summaries`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `conditions` `conditions_treatment_summaries` 
 ON `conditions_treatment_summaries`.`id` = `conditions_treatment_summaries_join`.`condition_id` 

WHERE
   `conditions`.`id` = 9 
   AND `conditions`.`id` IN (9) 
   AND (latest_review_id is not null) 
GROUP BY 
   treatment_reviews.id 
ORDER BY 
   treatment_summaries.reviews_count desc
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: Please post your query in a more readable manner. I'm having difficulty reading it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there is another issue, cause **GROUP BY** should not leave same lines (for given column), but anyway you can wrap it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ( YOUR_SQL_SELECT_WITH_EVERYTHING ) GROUP BY id
```

So the result you get will behave as another **table** and you can do all operations like **GROUP BY** again.